# Laravel use route into define custom macro

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

i'm define custom macro such as `link_image` and into that i want to use `{{ URL::route('profile') }}` . after inserting this below line i get error:

```
{{ HTML::image_link("{{ URL::route('profile') }}", 'public/images/close.png', '', 'Image 01') }}
```

**Error :**

```
 syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting ',' or ';'
```

My macro :

```
HTML::macro('image_link', function($url = '', $img='img/', $title ='' ,$alt='', $param = false, $active=true, $ssl=false)
{
    $url = $ssl==true ? URL::to_secure($url) : URL::to($url);  
    $img = HTML::image($img,$alt);
    $link = $active==true ? HTML::link($url, '#', $param) : $img;
    $link = str_replace('#', $img.$title ,$link);
    return $link;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the `"{{ }}"` around URL::route:

```
{{ HTML::image_link(URL::route('profile'), 'public/images/close.png', '', 'Image 01') }}
```